# How can 'cmd' be provided to the browser for Sentry (@sentry/nextjs package) using a custom webpack configuration in Next.js?

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, sentry

In my package json, Im using

```
"webpack": "5.58.1",
"@sentry/nextjs": "6.13.3",
"typescript": "4.0.5",
"next": "11.0.1",
```

I run `next build` and it compiles without errors.

Then I run `next dev` and I go look in the browser at http://localhost:3000/

I see this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cwd')
    at eval (VM244 parsers.js:42)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/parsers.js (_app.js?ts=1634221348526:3118)
    at Module.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:675)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:353)
    at eval (VM243 backend.js:9)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/backend.js (_app.js?ts=1634221348526:2975)
    at Module.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:675)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:353)
    at eval (VM220 index.js:42)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/index.js (_app.js?ts=1634221348526:3008)
    at Module.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:675)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:353)
    at eval (VM175 index.server.js:10)
    at Module../node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/esm/index.server.js (_app.js?ts=1634221348526:2909)
    at Module.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:675)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:37)
    at fn (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:353)
    at eval (sentry.client.config.js:2)
    at Module../sentry.client.config.js (_app.js?ts=1634221348526:2031)
    at Module.options.factory (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:675)
    at __webpack_require__ (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:37)
    at __webpack_exec__ (_app.js?ts=1634221348526:14966)
    at _app.js?ts=1634221348526:14967
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:86)
    at _app.js?ts=1634221348526:14968
    at webpackJsonpCallback (webpack.js?ts=1634221348526:1255)
    at _app.js?ts=1634221348526:9
```

In the `next.config.js` I have tried to suppress the error by adding this to my custom webpack configuration:

```
config.resolve.fallback =  {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false,
        "domain": false,
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "tty": false,
        "stream": false,
        "child_process": false,
        "process": false,
      };
```

I have also tried installing `"process": "0.11.10",` in my package.json, and then adding this to my custom webpack config in `next.config.js`:

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
        })
    ],
```

None of these have worked.

Any ideas about how I can solve this TypeError at runtime?

Comment: Where are you trying to use `cwd`?

Comment: ```global.process.cwd()) + "/";``` in node_modules/@sentry/node/esm/parsers.js

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'global.process': 'process/browser',
        })
    ],
```

and remove "process":false from

```
config.resolve.fallback =  {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false,
        "domain": false,
        "http": false,
        "https": false,
        "tty": false,
        "stream": false,
        "child_process": false,
        "process": false,
      };
```